# What is the relation between universal covering space and curvature of base manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Does anyone know what is the relation between universal covering space and curvature of base manifolds?

**Edit:** For example   If universal covering of a complete $3$-manifold $(M,g)$ 
 isometric to a Riemann product $N^2\times \Bbb R$ where $N^2$ is a complete
$2$-manifold with non-negative sectional curvature then what we can say about $(M,g)$?

Thanks

Comment: This is a rather broad and vague question. There is no single answer. Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: In the 3-manifold case, we know what the possible geometries are (on the universal cover).  See https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2012_MA4J2/geometry.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The universal covering space is a topological construction that makes no reference to smooth or Riemannian structures. If the base is a smooth manifold, then the universal covering space has a natural smooth structure defined by pulling back the smooth structure on the base by the universal covering map, and by construction the universal covering map becomes a local diffeomorphism.

If the base is a Riemannian manifold, then the pullback of the metric by the universal covering map is again a Riemannian metric, making the universal covering a simply connected Riemannian manifold, the universal covering map a local isometry, and the deck group acts by isometries.

If the base has a Riemannian metric with constant sectional curvature, then the universal covering space is isometric to one of the constant-curvature space forms and the base can be realized as the quotient of a space form by a representation of its fundamental group in the isometry group of the space form. This is very useful in low dimensions for translating topological questions into a form amenable to analysis by geometric tools.

Comment: Why wouldn’t the universal cover of a manifold (not necessarily Riemannian) be simply connected?

Comment: Universal covers are always simply connected.

Comment: You’re right. So I guess my question is, is being a manifold enough to guarantee the existence of a universal cover?

Comment: Yes for connected manifolds - in fact, to have a universal cover, a topological space just needs to be connected, locally path connected, and semi-locally simply connected. (If the manifold is not connected, then each connected component will have a universal cover.)